# hide webpage element partially

Tags: html, css

My webpage has static navigation menu at top, but is lowered a bit and background is visible above it. When text in page is scrolled down it goes beneath menu and then is again visible above the menu.
 How can I hide the part of text which is above menu. 
 Also the background will be an image.
If I place the text in `<div>` element below menu and set `overflow:auto`, scroll bar is then moved to the side of div element, not the page body as it is intended to be.

EDIT: Here is jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/EmpireGlitch/N9xg2/
HTML:

```
 <div class="topline">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="interpage_navigation">
            <li><a href="">Choice 1</a>

            </li>
            <li id="active_tab"><a href="">Choice 2</a>

            </li>
    </div>
    <div id="top_seperator"></div>
</div>
<div class="article">
     <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu .interpage_navigation li {
    background-color: rgba(25, 102, 25, 0.8);
}
.side, #top_seperator, #active_tab {
    background-color: rgba(50, 205, 50, 0.8);
}
.topline {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
#top_seperator {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
.menu {
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
}
.menu > ul {
    overflow: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin:0px;
    //border: solid blue 1px;
}
.menu li {
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
}
.menu .interpage_navigation li {
    width:120px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-family: verdana, arial;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.article {
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding:20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 125px;
    left: 30%;
    right:15%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Can we see some of your code, we aren't psychics :)

Comment: You should really add some code or perhaps a jsfiddle if you want us to be able to help you...

Comment: You should post an image

Comment: Please edit your code into the question rather than just linking to a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `:before` pseudo element to create an element to place over the top of the page - http://jsfiddle.net/N9xg2/1/

The problem with this is that it is dependant on having a solid colour.

You may want to re-think how you're positioning the article - using position:absolute is going to really limit you.

Comment: I run in this problem when I added image background. I need a solution for non-solid color backgrounds. I should add this note to question...

Answer (score 0):

My solution was similar to Richard's, except I just gave `.menu` a background (and tweaked its padding).

```
.menu {
    margin:0px;
    padding-left:100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/N9xg2/2/)

But I know you want to use an image background. You can solve that problem by using:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/N9xg2/4/)